# setAttribute not working in IE7

Tags: javascript, html, css

The below code works fine in IE9 and IE8 but not working in IE7. May I know, What's wrong with this code?

**JS Code:**

```
if(innerwidth>1000 && innerwidth<1500){
     var fileref=document.createElement("link");
     fileref.setAttribute("rel","stylesheet");  
     fileref.setAttribute("type","text/css");
     fileref.setAttribute("media","all");
     fileref.setAttribute("href","1001aboveie7.css");
     document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);
}
```

Thanks:)

Comment: How do you know that the problem lies with `setAttribute`? Can you see the element added to the DOM? Can you see that it has no attributes set on it at all?

Comment: css not loading at all.the problem lies in this block of code only.so setAttribute won't support in IE7?if so any alternative?

Comment: Can you use jQuery or some other library like it? They smooth over most cross-browser issues like this.

Comment: See: http://quirksmode.org/dom/core/. Scroll down to setAttribute and read the recommendation on how to handle attributes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this, it works with my IE7

```
if (innerwidth > 1000 && innerwidth < 1500) {
    var fileref = document.createElement("link");
    fileref.rel = "stylesheet";
    fileref.type = "text/css";
    fileref.media = "all";
    fileref.href = "1001aboveie7.css";
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IE7 do not support:

```
setAttribute
```

you use to use base attribute to add it.

var foo = document.createElement("link");
foo.rel = "stylesheet";